# Protractor: Failed: protractor.getInstance is not a function

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have installed protractor **globally**, and after locally.
I am using this code:

```
var protractor = require('protractor');
var ptor, driver;
ptor.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(protractor.By.tagName("iframe")));
driver.findElement(protractor.by.css(".cke_editable")).sendKeys("123");
```

And get this message:

> Failed: protractor.getInstance is not a function

What am I do wrong?

**P.S.** I havn't "*lib/protractor.js*", only "*bin/protractor*".

Comment: what version of protractor you are using?

Comment: @SudharsanSelvarj Version 3.2.2

Comment: I have a similar problem, but don't understand your code completely. How can `ptor.switchTo()`  work, if `ptor` is not initialized yet?

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you are using `var ptor = protractor.getInstance()`, just get the driver from the browser

```
var browser = require("protractor").protractor.browser;
var driver = browser.driver;
```