# Need help to set protractor.browser in the code

Tags: protractor

Actually, need to set instance of protractor, hence, written,

```
var ptor = protractor.getInstance();

var driver = ptor.driver;
// Switching to frame

ptor.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(protractor.By.id('NavBarGloablQuickCreate')));
```

For the above code, it was instructed to set :

[Protractor: Failed: protractor.getInstance is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989704/protractor-failed-protractor-getinstance-is-not-a-function)

```
var browser = require("protractor").protractor.browser;
var driver = browser.driver;

But while setting it in the beginning :
for example :

it("Creating Customer",function() 
{

var browser = require("protractor").protractor.browser;

browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Error is there, saying :

> Cannot find the module 'protractor'

Pls. help

Comment: Can I ask for what reason you need to do this? There may be better suited approaches

Comment: Actually, I am going to run automate script for Dynamic CRM  Quick Screen view. And It's under a  Iframe. Need to place the cursor on the firstname and then TAB for the next fields, hence used the below code : 

var ptor = protractor.getInstance();  var driver = ptor.driver; ptor.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(protractor.By.id('NavBarGloablQuickCreate'))); driver.findElement(protractor.By.id('firstname_i')).sendKeys('protractor.Key.TAB'); driver.findElement(protractor.By.id('firstname_i')).sendKeys('John');

Comment: #DublinDev Kindly help.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand why you need to specifically declare Protractor. It is possible to switch to Iframes using protractor [see here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/31624/switching-to-iframe-using-protractor). Is there angular code within the Iframe or is it non-angular?

Comment: I have used that code. I have tried all possibilities  in Protractor by trying this piece of code which is working as stated in Stack Exchange. ( https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/31624/switching-to-iframe-using-protractor?rq=1)

 By running this code, it says, that it unable to recognize the element. It's non-angular.

Comment: Is the content of the Iframe using angular?

Comment: #DublinDev : No uses of angular I have seen inside the Iframe.

Comment: In Protractor, if we want to execute any piece of java script, we have to use like :

browser.executeScript("window.onload = document.getElementById('NavBarGloablQuickCreate').contentWindow.document.getElementById('firstname_i').value = 'Indra'");

Here, we are successful only placing the first name and after that, we are unable select the next field by any code, used protractor/java script, but nothing is working for us here. I am not sure what is happening here. Also, noticed, protractor code is getting compiled first and then that piece of java script.

Comment: Through protractor code, I am unable to put the text on the text box, but if I implicitly click on mouse over the text filed, the text is placing. Also did field.click(), and focus in java script, but nothing is working.

Comment: #DublinDev : Pls. help

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `.getWebElement()` in the original answer but since you said in your comment that you are open to setting `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` could you try this approach. Just be aware that with this setting all of your code **will need be be changed to async/await style** or may not run in the order you expect.

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = { 
    framework: 'jasmine', 
    seleniumAddress: 'localhost:4444/wd/hub', 
    capabilities: { 
        browserName: 'chrome' 
    }, 
    specs: ['spec.js'], 
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    jasmineNodeOpts: { 
        isVerbose: true, 
        includeStackTrace: true, 
        showColors: true, 
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 3000000 
    } 
};
```

**Spec.js**

```
it('switch to browser', async () => {
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

    await browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id('NavBarGloablQuickCreate')).getWebElement());
    let firstNField = element(by.id("firstname_i"));
    console.log(await firstNField.isPresent());
    await firstNField.sendKeys('firstN');
    console.log(firstNField.getAttribute('value'))
});
```

**Old Answer: Non-async/await** Can you try this and let me know how it goes?

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id("NavBarGloablQuickCreate")).getWebElement());
browser.driver.sleep(1000);
element(by.id('firstname_i')).sendKeys('Indra');
browser.driver.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: After using this code, now while running the code by : protractor conf.js, only first the browser opens with no URL and it's stopped. come back to terminal. If you want, I can share the total code. Will you pls. share your emailid, cause here the line no, is limited.

Comment: #DublinDev : Pls. help.

Comment: @user2637375 Are you setting SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER in your config file?

Comment: No, in my config file : exports.config =  {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
 },
specs: ['spec.js'],
jasmineNodeOpts: {
isVerbose: true,
includeStackTrace: true,
showColors : true,
defaultTimeoutInterval: 3000000
}

};

Comment: #DublinDev : Please help me what to add more here.

Comment: #DublinDev : Could you pls help to set the same ?

Comment: @user2637375 when trying the code I posted locally I am also seeing the same issue as you so there is some issue with what I posted. I haven't worked with iframes in a while so the specific details of it are not coming back to me at the minute. Could you update your post with the additional information you posted in the comments, this will encourage other users to help also

Comment: As you have said, I have set, SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false, But while running,  only chrome instance is up, but nothing is opened. I have used : it("Creating Customer",function() 
{
 
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

// Open the URL 

browser.get("http://XXXXXX:XXXX%4012345@XX.XXX.XX.102/TestLab/main.aspx");

Comment: I am trying here the QuickView form of MS-Dynamic CRM. The text fileds are under IFrame. Through the below java script, it's access able :  //focus to fnamre

//enter fname value
browser.executeScript("window.onload = document.getElementById('NavBarGloablQuickCreate').contentWindow.document.getElementById('firstname_i').value = 'rupam'"); But only first name is selected, if we try to do for the rest fields, it's not working.  Hence, decided to do it through protractor code, hence tried ,

Comment: browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id("NavBarGloablQuickCreate"))); and then browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id("NavBarGloablQuickCreate"))); and tried : element(by.id('firstname_i')).sendKeys('Indra');  But here, it says elemnts not contactable.

Comment: @user2637375 I added another approach using async/await

Comment: Ok, Trying now.

Comment: @user2637375 I forgot to add the waitForAngularEnabled(false) in the async style. I also updated the non-async format so you can try that if it is easier for you

Comment: For the above code, the error throws here : firstNField.isPresent is not a function. Type error :  firstNField.isPresent is not a function.

Comment: @user my mistake,  had isPresent declared twice. Updated answer